# How do I populate fields on my page with a drop down list selection?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am still very new to the whole ASP.NET MVC / AJAX / jQuery thing.
I am trying to populate a couple of text boxes on my webpage based on a selection in a drop down list.
However, based on my current code, I do not seem to be able to populate those text boxes with data. My initial suspect is that the 'change' event is not being triggered.
Any advice is appreciated.

I am using the MVC Scaffolding to generate the corresponding Controllers and Views. I have added an extra function to return a JSON object to be used to populate the text boxes and I am pretty sure the return is correct as I do see the JSON data if I enter the request manually.

Create.cshtml - Drop down list, textbox and script in question.

```
... Some html codes ...

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="OneTimeFee">One Time Fee</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("OneTimeFee", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

... Some other html codes ...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#OneTimeFee').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetOneTimeFee", "FeeHistory")',
            data: { onetimefeeid: $('#OneTimeFee').val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Amount').val(data.Amount);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
                $('#Amount').val('');
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

FeeHistory.cs

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetOneTimeFee(String onetimefeeid)
        {
            Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(onetimefeeid);
            one_time_fees one_Time_Fees = await db.one_time_fees.FindAsync(id);
            if(one_Time_Fees == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            return Json(one_Time_Fees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I was expecting to see the Amount textbox to be the value from the database via the JSON object. However, I do not see any changes to that textbox.

If I use Firefox to Inspect Element, the only error I get is that `Reference Error: $ is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this before your other script tag

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The `Reference Error: $ is not defined` is because JQuery is not imported

Comment: Seems to be working. Although I am curious to why Microsoft puts the jQuery and Bootstrap scripts at the bottom of the body at the _Layout.cshtml page then.

Comment: Are you rendering with your _layout page?

Comment: I believe so. Using their template to play around with.

Comment: If it worked, can you please accept my answer?